# pip dependency management with --editable pins path to src folder

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I'm lost on the best way to track dependencies for a python application when installing it in editable mode. In a simple example, let's say I have a project structure like the following.

```
test_proj
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── src
│   ├── test_proj
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── sum.py
├── tests
│   ├── conftest.py
│   └── test_sum.py
└── tox.ini
```

Then I want to install this project in an editable way with:

```
root@5ec46f98afa7:/home/test_proj# python -m venv $(pwd)/.venv
root@5ec46f98afa7:/home/test_proj# source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) root@5ec46f98afa7:/home/test_proj# pip install -e .
Obtaining file:///home/test_proj
Installing collected packages: test-proj
  Running setup.py develop for test-proj
Successfully installed test-proj
```

Finally, I go to create my requirements.txt file, but pip pinned my local install into my environment.

```
(.venv) root@5ec46f98afa7:/home/test_proj# pip freeze
# Editable Git install with no remote (test-proj==0.0.post0.dev1+ga0aeded.dirty)
-e /home/test_proj/src
```

This makes sense, since it is installed in my virtual environment so it should show up in pip freeze. However, if I take this file and try to use it to install the dependencies on another machine, the pip install -r requirements.txt command will fail.

```
(.venv) root@5ec46f98afa7:/home/test_proj# pip install -r requirements.txt
ERROR: File "setup.py" not found. Directory cannot be installed in editable mode: /home/test_proj/src
```

It's looking for a setup.py file in the "/src" directory, which doesn't exist and I don't think it makes sense to put one there since I already have one in my root directory.
So at this point, I either manually remove that line from my requirements.txt file, or use a different method of dependency tracking like pipenv. I'm trying to keep it as simple as possible on my team though.

Here are the relevant parts of my setup.cfg file.

```
[options]
zip_safe = False
packages = find:
include_package_data = True
package_dir =
    =src    

[options.packages.find]
 where = src
 exclude =
     tests
```

Am I missing something in my dependency management workflow? Thanks.